# Some users' chat icons are sometimes displaying as default gravatar depending on size

Tags: bug, chat, profile-picture, gravatar

In [Ask Ubuntu chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), there are some users (e.g. [cl-netbox](https://askubuntu.com/users/260935/cl-netbox) and [Thomas Ward](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward)) of which the user icon is recently displaying wrongly most of the time:

[image: incorrect icon cl-netbox]

[image: incorrect icon Thomas Ward]

cl-netbox' icon on all sites id a blue square with the white letters `cl`. It shows up this way in the user list on the right and even in the popup bubble opening when I click his name. However, some chat messages have him with a default Gravatar (those green random triangles) showing up as you can see in the screenshot above. Not all messages show up the default icon though, it probably depends on the displayed icon size.

I tried both Firefox and Chrome, with and without add-ons, logged in and logged out, all show the same behaviour. Strange thing is that initially only cl-netbox was displaying incorrectly on my Windows 10 work laptop, but now also Thomas Ward is displaying incorrectly on my home Ubuntu notebook.

Hard refreshing using Ctrl+F5 sometimes changed the appearance of the icon on the left to some of the messages, but not necessarily all of them, and not always to the correct direction. Later posted messages may still show up with either icon...

I know this bug is very strange and probably difficult to reproduce for someone else, so it might probably be necessary that you provide me instructions on how to investigate the problem locally further and provide important information.

Comment: I don't see that - I see a blue icon with cl on it for the user avatar on chat. Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Same thing as the avatar on their chat profile page: http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/112690/cl-netbox

Comment: What we *do* know is that Gravatar has been flaky lately and this is likely some more of the same :(

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I was able to reproduce it with both Firefox and Chrome and both with addons enabled and disabled, but only on this single machine @Oded

Comment: Could be the way that machine is routed, perhaps clearing the DNS cache would help?

Comment: @Oded I ran `ipconfig /flushdns` as admin and hard-refreshed the chat site, but still see the green default icon showing up, unfortunately.

Comment: If you go directly to the image on gravatar and refresh a few times, what happens? I suspect an issue on their end (and not much for us to do).

Comment: @Oded When I directly access the Gravatar icon http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/34bc9c94a87d9cef8d7b410b2bc8a71d , it always is the correct blue one. It is also always correct in the main sites and even in chat in the user list in the right side bar and in the popup bubble of the username.

Comment: @Oded I have also seen this and with the same user in the same room. Both ByteCommander and I are in Europe. Could it be a regional gravatar server issue or something?

Comment: @terdon - could very well be, though I don't know how to test that. I too am in Europe, but not seeing the issue.

Comment: I see the issue too on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends. Here's a picture [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ifp7.png) that shows two different gravatars for the same user.

Comment: @Oded This has been observed as well in a stackoverflow chat room. It appears that only the bigger images seem to be cached somewhere and therefore show the default icon. Clear your browsers cache and you might experience the same as well. The default icon is shown as well on the right side of the chat.

Comment: I'm seeing this now.